# creating a main bash toolbox script calling tools as separate scripts

Tags: bash, shell

Hard to find a proper title for my question!
Probably much more simple than what I think, sorry about that!

Aim:

I would like to build a collection of bash scripts (tools) all under the control of a main bash script that handles general parameters and loads shared functions then gives the hand to the tool code.

I am inspiring from what I often use from java apps which can be called like

```
mainApp task param1 param2 ... paramn
```

where 'mainApp' is the main bash script, 'task' is one of the possible tools present in a subfolder (/tools) and 'param(1..n)' are parameters to pass to the task script.

The 'task' scripts are more than just bash functions, they can be quite large and include their own testing and evaluations and I would like to keep them out of the main script for modularity and readability. I do not like 20 pages long bash scripts ;-)

Some task scripts will call others which are more universal.

Q:

I do not directly see how I can handle the argument "task" in mainApp to select and run the second script based on the "task" value (should I use case and/or eval ?)

Can you please help me structure this nicely or point me to a primer or to proper wording to search for this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in `mainApp`:

```
#! /bin/bash

T=/path/to/tasks

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]
then
    echo 'usage'
    exit 1
fi

task="$1"
shift
if [[ -x "$T/$task" ]]
then
    exec "$T/$task" "$@"
else
    echo "no such task $task"
fi
```

so you don't have to change your `mainApp` script if you add tasks or change parameters.

Your tasks should all be in `tasks` directory
and  must have executable permission.

Comment: Thanks Diego,
Will the task also receive variables and custom functions and defined in the main script?

Comment: Exported environment variables yes. If you want functions you can source them in the main script and tasks.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot for your hints. Never made such complex script before, quite cool actually.